# How to detect, in VBA, with/after previous in an interactive sequence?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I created a macro that calculates the total length of animation in a slide.

It works perfectly... for the Main Sequence.

I came up with a problem when dealing with interactive sequences.

Say I have a sequence that is started by a bookmark in a media.

Even though in the interactive sequence you can use with/after previous, when inspecting the VBA object you get on the property `Effect.Timing.TriggerType` the value `msoAnimTriggerOnMediaBookmark`.

While technically correct, that's not the value I'm looking for.

Does anyone know how to solve this?